# Condition setting problem over custom build decorator in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a custom build decorator in Django.

my `models.py`:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique="True", blank=False)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Industry = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

class Inspector(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='inspector_releted_user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    gmail = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=False, unique=True)
    nid = models.IntegerField(blank=False, unique=True)
    inspector_varified = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I want to build a decorator that will allow the user to pass by satisfying the following 3 **conditions**:

1. `user` is active and logged in
2. `is_Inspector` value is True
3. `inspector_varified`'s value is also `True` (`inspector_varified` is in under `Inspector` class)

my `decorators.py`:

```
def inspector_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='app2:request_login'):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        lambda u: u.is_active and u.is_Inspector,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

It is maintaining conditions 1 & 2, but condition-3 is not satisfied by it. How can I code for it also?

Comment: Since you use a `ForeignKey`, a `User` can have *multiple related* `Inspector`s, so I don't think it makes much sense, likely you should use a `OneToOneField`.

Comment: How can I satisfy the **condition-3**, when I use the `OneToOneField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modeling itself does not make much sense: by using a `ForeignKey`, a `User` can have *multiple* `Inspector` objects, so there is no single `Inspector`. Likely that is not how you want to model this.

You can convert the `ForeignKey` into a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField), this is in essence a `ForeignKey` with a uniqness constraint, so that means that each `Inspector` will refer to a *different* user.

```
class Inspector(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        myCustomeUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='inspector_releted_user'
    )
    # …
```

then we can check this with:

```
def check(user):
    try:
        return user.is_authenticated and user.is_Inspector and user.inspector_related_user.inspector_varified
    except AttributeError:
        return False
```

then we can validate this with:

```
def inspector_required(function=None, redirect_field_name=REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME, login_url='app2:request_login'):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(
        check,
        login_url=login_url,
        redirect_field_name=redirect_field_name
    )
    if function:
        return actual_decorator(function)
    return actual_decorator
```

Still however the modeling does not look very good, especially since `is_Inspector` does *not* need to be a field of the user model: we can simply check if a `User` is an inspector by checking if there is an `Inspector` object which points to that user.

Furthermore field names are written in *snake_case*, so `is_inspector`, not <s>`is_Inspector`</s>.